# how to fix this error android: Could not find class 'com.owlike.genson.Genson'

Tags: android, web-services, jakarta-ee, genson

```
final Collaborateur collaborateur =  new Genson().deserialize(scanner.nextLine(),Collaborateur.class);
```

> 05-17 12:00:20.058: E/dalvikvm(3150): Could not find class 'com.owlike.genson.Genson', referenced from method com.example.ayit.MainActivity$2.run

Comment: Download the jar in libs from https://owlike.github.io/genson/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into [this](https://owlike.github.io/genson/) to remove an error.

download jar file from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/owlike/genson/1.4/genson-1.4.jar) and add it into your project.

I hope this will resolve your error.

Comment: I have already downloaded it and built the path in eclipse but it still gives me this error

Comment: you are using eclipse not android studio ?

Comment: If you are using eclipse you suppose to add jar from build path !! use this link https://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/eclipse-android-tutorial-working-with-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your project either .jar or the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```